# How can I put a totally new prestashop store on a sub-domain I created?

Tags: subdomain, prestashop

I need a bit of advice. I have an e-commerce site on www.mydomain.com and I have now created a sub domain that will have a totally new store running on it (all installed any ready to go). I use prestashop and I want to point a category on www.mydomain.com to my new sub domain www.mydomain/sub.com. Can this be done? How would I do it?

Comment: if it is a subdomain, would you be pointing it to subdomain.mydomain.com?

Comment: If I understand your question, you could stick the page in question into the HTML element I-Frame or similar?

Comment: Do you have control over the templates in prestashop? Can you add php code to them? If no then you'll have trouble linking a category to your subdomain. If you can create content links just do that and place it some where in the sidebar or make a graphic and link that.

Answer (score 1):

> www.mydomain/sub.com

either does not make sense or will confuse everyone or I'm not getting your question right

> www.mydomain.com/sub

is a subdirectory

while

> www.sub.mydomain.com

is a subdomain

In general context subdirectory and subdomain should behaves almost the same way. For SEO, the safe approach is to use subdirectory instead of subdomain e.g. http://www.whitefireseo.com/site-architecture/subdomain-or-subfolder-post-panda/360/ (there are a lot more preferences, feel free to do some searches)

The general directory structures on your server would be as follows for both subdirectory and subdomain case

- `mydomain.com/` (your domain www.mydomain.com points to this directory)

  - `sub` (your subdomain or subdirectory simple points to this directory)
  - `other` directories and files

As a result, what you need to do is the following 2 simple steps

**Step 1**: Create directory "sub" inside directory "mydomain.com" (this should be a breeze if you have access to cPanel or SFTP access to the directory "mydomain.com" and you have "write" permission to it

**Step 2**: Install a new prestashop website inside "mydomain.com/sub/"

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sub domain then it can't be possible as mydomain.com/sub.com but you can create it as sub.mydomain.com. If you are ready to make sub domain then log in into control panel of web hosting and then choose option as create sub domain. You sub domain facility available on your web hosting plan. I hope you can understand about sub domain.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

So.. you havee installed PRESTASHOP in www.mydomain.com and your store will stay there.
The only thing you want to do is to read a category from prestashop and put the results in subdomain.mydomain.com.
If I understood well so.. this will be done in 3 ways:

1. you will connect to the old database and read from there anything you want to apply in the subdomain
2. you will use the prestashop webservice (the old one, installed in www.mydomain.com) and then conform to the documentation about collecting data trough webservice have some results
3. if you wish to only display a link to the category, you can copy the category URL, but in this situation you will ensure that category never ever changes its id or name or changing the seo friendly url structure.

Hope is helpfull for you